# Can Avro schema specify a minimum array length?

Tags: arrays, avro

Can a complex record array in Avro be defined with a minimum size?

I want my array to always have at least one element. How do I restrict that?

Comment: Please explain more with data

Answer (score 1):

There is no such specificiation. Of course min size would be zero, though.

With [apache-kafka](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka), you could define your own `Interceptor` to inspect and reject messages with an empty array. Or use [apache-kafka-streams](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-streams) or [ksqldb](/questions/tagged/ksqldb) to filter those messages out.